# Highcharts-vue - Using the tooltip / label formatter()

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I previously used the label formatter to customise the Y-Axis labels in a chart, but I'm not sure how to do this using highcharts-vue because of scope. 
See the following pseudo code;

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {

      currencySymbol: '$',

      title: 'My Chart',
      points: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
      chartType: 'Spline',
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Sin chart'
        },
        yAxis: {
          gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
          labels: {
              style: {
                  color: '#fff'
              },

              formatter: function () {
                  return this.currencySymbol + this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this)
              }

        },
        series: [{
          data: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
          color: '#6fcd98'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
```

In the full app, the currencySymbol property is updated in the response of an AJAX call.

Is there an elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recommended way would be to use [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), JS [Arrow function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp), and call `Highcharts.Axis.prototype.defaultLabelFormatter`.

First of all we need to move a whole chart configuration inside of a computed property, e.g called `chartOptions`. Then we just need to refactor the formatter function a bit, so that it would be arrow function, and create the variable with symbol defined in component data (!important). After that, the `this` keyword will indicate on the component object, and refer the symbol direcly by calling the variable created on the top of the function. I prepared the example, so please take a lok on it.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-icuzw

Code:

```js
data() {
    return {
      currencySymbol: "$",
      title: "My Chart",
      points: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
      chartType: "Spline"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      var symbol = this.currencySymbol;

      return {
        chart: {
          type: "spline"
        },
        title: {
          text: "Sin chart"
        },
        yAxis: {
          gridLineDashStyle: "Dot",
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: "#000"
            },
            formatter: label => {
              return (
                symbol + Highcharts.Axis.prototype.defaultLabelFormatter.call(label)
              );
            }
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
            color: "#6fcd98"
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  }
```

Kind regards!

Comment: Another super helpful response! Thank you @daniel_s. 
But, can I assume that any dynamic requirements will still need to be configured in data() as opposed to computed()? The same chart still needs to be real-time updated via ajax. 
For me, the **backgroundColor** and **plotBorderColor** and obviously **series** are updated on a per chart basis.

Comment: Got it!! I'm updating the rest of the chart in the same was as you do with the *currencySymbol* in the above example. Perfect! I just have one issue left and thats formatting the tooltip whereby in my original code I used to call a globally accessible function to customise the format based on locale. This no longer works, nor feels like the most appropriate solution. I'll create another (hopefully just one more) question.

Comment: Calling my own formatter function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067208/highcharts-vue-calling-my-own-tooltip-label-formatter-function