# Highcharts-vue - Calling my own tooltip label formatter function

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I have been trying to call my own function for formatting the x and y axis values in a tooltip in Highcharts vue. 
Consider the following;

```
data() {
    return {
      currencySymbol: "$",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      var symbol = this.currencySymbol;

      return {
        chart: {
          type: "spline"
        },
        title: {
          text: "Sin chart"
        },
        yAxis: {
          gridLineDashStyle: "Dot",
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: "#000"
            },
            formatter: label => {
              return (
                symbol + Highcharts.Axis.prototype.defaultLabelFormatter.call(label)
              );
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + 
                this.formatNumber(this.y, this.fractionalDigits, this.locale, this.currencySymbol);
          }                    
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
            color: "#6fcd98"
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  }
```

The labels work fine but the tooltip function call will not work. I have tried putting my *formatNumber()* function in both *methods()* and outside of any of the Vue hooks. Neither work.
Note that *fractionDigits*, *locale* and *currencySymbol* have been resolved at this point.
Wondering if someone can advise on the correct approach?

Also note that the formatter works when I remove the call to my *formatNumber()* function. It's lack of scope appears to be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I should assume that `this.formatNumber`, `this.fractionDigits`, `this.locale`, and `this.currencySymbol` would be references to a component's internal data, then the problem would occurs because of `this` context within tooltip's formatter function, which does not actually indicate on the component, but on the object on which the formatter was called, namely the [TooltipFormatterContextObject](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.TooltipFormatterContextObject).

In order to fix it, you can save appropriate context in the beginning of the `chartOptions` computed property function, and just refer it when calling component functions. Please take a look on the example below, where I've put the 'template' function named like yours, and presented how it could be implemented.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-wqwzu

Kind regards!

Comment: Mid air collision! :-) Unless there is any reason not to, I'll probably stick with my solution for this based on the reason given in my answer. But I think your post more closely answers the question.

Comment: Thanks @daniel_s. If you feel like flexing your highcharts muscles again soon, I've posed a new question. :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084961/highcharts-vue-using-inheritance-multiple-graphs-have-common-properties

Comment: It's a pure pleasure to answer those questions ;) I'll take a look on it tomorrow.

Comment: @daniel_s the explanation makes sense but I don't understand the Live example link above. Is it possible that link no longer represents the intended codesandbox example? I'm struggling with a similar challenge trying to use the `pointFormatter` function in a histogram chart and `this` becomes the Vue object instead of the pointFormatter data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most elegant but I found a solution to this problem for myself.

I created a utility js file called *helper.js*, added my exported function (I'll need it in other places anyway) and put it in a directory called *utils*.

The contents are as follows;

```
export function formatNumber(number, maxFractionDigits, locale, currencySymbol) {
     // function logic here
}
```

Then I imported same into my component and simply called the method as follows;

```
 import {formatNumber} from "../../utils/helper";
    export default {
     data() {
       return {
         currencySymbol: "$",
       };
     },
    computed: {
      chartOptions() {
        var symbol = this.currencySymbol;

        return {
          chart: {
            type: "spline"
          },
          title: {
            text: "Sin chart"
          },
          ...
          tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
              return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' + 
                  formatNumber(this.y, this.fractionalDigits, this.locale, this.currencySymbol);
            }                    
          },
        series: [
            {
            data: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
            color: "#6fcd98"
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  }
}
```