# Highcharts-vue - Using inheritance. Multiple graphs with common properties

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm trying to apply DRY principles to my Highcharts Vue implementation.

I have a few highcharts in my Vue component, most of which are the same except for some labelling and the series data.
I've been trying to abstract out the common properties without success.
Consider the following Vue component;

```
<template>
    <div>
        <highcharts class="chart" :options="chartOptions" ref="lineChart1"></highcharts>
    </div>
        <highcharts class="chart" :options="chartOptions" ref="lineChart2"></highcharts>
    </div>
</template>
```

I would like to use common chart options and then try and update the series dynamically.

```
computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      return {
        chart: {
          type: "spline"
        },
        title: {
          text: "chart1"
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: [10, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5],
            color: "#6fcd98"
          }
        ]
      };
    }
  },
mounted() {
 this.fetchChart1()
 this.fetchChart2()
}
methods: {
   fetchChart1: function () {
      fetch(`${this.serverURL}/chart1`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(json => { 
            const lineChart = this.$refs.lineChart1
            lineChart.chart.series[0] = json.series
            lineChart.title.text = json.title
         })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error))
    },
    fetchChart2: function () {
      fetch(`${this.serverURL}/chart2`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(json => { 
            const lineChart = this.$refs.lineChart2
            lineChart.chart.series[0] = json.series
            lineChart.title.text = json.title
         })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error))
    },

}
```

I'm not even sure if what I'm attempting is possible but I have managed to get two charts loading using the approach above, the issue is individually accessing and updating some of their properties.
The chart referencing comes from the following example which I appreciate does not use the same wrapper but I have utilized this approach to update the charts in realtime.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jjyqvv0k13

(see lineChart example)

Comment: Could you give me the example where you've put the above implementation, or if it exists in the attached example just direct me where can I find that code?

Comment: Sorry, I should be clear and say that the above is not a working example, it's me trying to show the approach I'm attempting to achieve the desired functionality. I'm not actually able to get it to work, hence why I'm here. :-) So maybe the answer is that my approach is wrong. I'm not sure to be honest but feel I should not have to copy large configuration options for very similar charts in the interest of adhering to the DRY principle. Make sense?

Comment: Hi, I think this demo can be a good example for you (charts created in the for loop): https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8kmyv.